# Getting Context path

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am developing a dynamic web project j2ee web application using eclipse. I have an existing jasper report file in .jrxml format found in web-inf/jasperreports folder. How do I access these files from my java classes in the src folder. I am not even sure if context path is the right term for the root folder of the application so please enlighten me too on this part.

I am using by the way spring webflow. how do i get or initialize the object servlet context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServletContext.getRealPath` method can be used to get the context path. `ServletContext.getRealPath("/")` returns the webapp root path. Path for `WEB-INF/jasperreports` would be:

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
String reportPath = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/jasperreports");
```

You can initialize you java classes from a `Servlet` of `ServletContextListener` where you can get reference for `ServletContext` by respectively the inherited `getServletContext()` and the `servletContextEvent.getServletContext()`.

Comment: To be more precise: the `getRealPath()` "converts" a relative webcontent path to an absolute disk file system path, which you can further use in the usual `java.io` stuff. On the other hand, you can also use `getResource()` or even `getResourceAsStream()` here.

Comment: I am using spring's webflow. How do i get or initialize the object ServletContext in the flow.